# How do I get the first and last item of a set in GLPK

Tags: linear-programming, ampl

I have a college exercise that I need to create a linear programming model from an academic paper. This has to be written in Gusek software which uses GLPK as a resolver.
The article defines sets in this way

DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijpe.2020.107742
[image: Table of sets]

My doubt is on the $ K^i $ set. I don't know how to represent the beginning and the end as the article explains for a model in GLPK code.
How could I do it? This doubt therefore solves my doubt about the $N$ and $N^i$ set as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with GLPK, but since it's based on AMPL, the following AMPL implementation might be of some help:

```
set I;
set J;
set K {I};

param J0 {i in I} symbolic = "0" & i;
param JT {i in I} symbolic = "T" & i;

set N {i in I} = {J0[i],JT[i]} union J;
set Nall = (union {i in I} {J0[i],JT[i]}) union J;
```

GLPK uses only a subset of AMPL, however, so to get these statements to work in GLPK you might need to make some changes.